# bs4 парсинг определенных строк из таблицы HTML

Tags: python, bs4, web-scraping

прошу помощи, вот из таблицы такого вида:

```
    <h1>Modems</h1>

<a href="..">zurück</a>
<br />
<br />

<table class="main">
    <tr>
        <th>ModemId</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Current state</th>
        <th>Last Status</th>
        <th>Send CMD</th>
        <th>Current Library</th>
        <th>CMD History</th>
        <th>REPLY History</th>
        <th>CSV/PDF Report</th>
        <th>Sensor Data Export</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Modem RU001</td>
        <td>SIGN</td>
        <td style="background: #F23353">OFFLINE</td>
        <td><a href="status.jsp?id=RU001">status</a></td>

        <td><a href="cmd.jsp?id=RU001">cmd</a></td>


        <td><a href="library.jsp?id=RU001">library</a></td>

        <td><a href="cmd_hist.jsp?id=RU001">cmd history</a></td>

        <td><a href="reply_hist.jsp?id=RU001">reply history</a></td>


        <td><a href="report_pdf.jsp?id=RU001">report</a></td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Modem RU002</td>
        <td>SIGN</td>
        <td style="background: #F23353">OFFLINE</td>
        <td><a href="status.jsp?id=RU002">status</a></td>

        <td><a href="cmd.jsp?id=RU002">cmd</a></td>


        <td><a href="library.jsp?id=RU002">library</a></td>

        <td><a href="cmd_hist.jsp?id=RU002">cmd history</a></td>

        <td><a href="reply_hist.jsp?id=RU002">reply history</a></td>


        <td><a href="report_pdf.jsp?id=RU002">report</a></td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Modem RU00n</td>
        <td>SIGN</td>
        <td style="background: #F23353">OFFLINE</td>
        <td><a href="status.jsp?id=RU00n">status</a></td>

        <td><a href="cmd.jsp?id=RU00n">cmd</a></td>


        <td><a href="library.jsp?id=RU00n">library</a></td>

        <td><a href="cmd_hist.jsp?id=RU00n">cmd history</a></td>

        <td><a href="reply_hist.jsp?id=RU00n">reply history</a></td>


        <td><a href="report_pdf.jsp?id=RU00n">report</a></td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
```

Мне необходим список словарей вида: [{'id' : 'RU001', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}]. Я пока смог сделать с помощью итераций вида:

```
reqOnline = requests.get(url_online)
onlSoup = BeautifulSoup(reqOnline.content, 'lxml')
getOnline = onlSoup.find_all('td')
tuplOnline = []
for i in getOnline:
    if 'Modem' in i.text:
        tempId = (i.text.split(' ')[1])
    elif 'ONLINE' in i.text:
        status = 'ONLINE'
        dictOnl = {'id': tempId,
                   'status': status}
    elif 'OFFLINE' in i.text:
        status = 'OFFLINE'
        dictOnl = {'id': tempId,
                   'status': status}
        tuplOnline.append(dictOnl)
```

Ну сами понимаете громозкость данного кода. Есть ли у bs4 или у других инструментов python что то более лаконичное и более адекватное?

Comment: `result = [{"id": tr.contents[0].text, "status": tr.contents[2].text} for tr in onlSoup.find_all("tr")[1:]]`.

Comment: result = [{"id": tr.contents[1].get_text(), "status": tr.contents[5].get_text()} for tr in onlSoup.find_all("tr")[1:]] - Вот так заработало! )

Comment: Спасибо большое! ) не знал что так можно передавать первый параметр в генераторах списка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Пример:***

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    result = []

    trs = soup.find_all('tr')[1:]
    for tr in trs:
        tds = tr.find_all('td')

        name = tds[0].getText()
        status = tds[2].getText()
        result.append({
            'id': name,
            'status': status,
        })

    return result


def main():
    with open('index.html') as f:
        html = f.read()

    result = parse(html)
    print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***stdout:***

```py
[{'id': 'Modem RU001', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'Modem RU002', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}, {'id': 'Modem RU00n', 'status': 'OFFLINE'}]
```

Comment: Вариант рабочий! Спасибо большое, можно пару уточнений? getText() и get_text() разные функции? зачем запятая после status?

Comment: @HuanGi `getText()` — это псевдоним для `get_text()`, т. е. одна и та же функция. А запятая после `status`, т. е. завершающая запятая — просто правило хорошего тона. Так легче добавлять/копировать строки.